# glDrawArrays weirdly draws array

Tags: c++, opengl

When I try to draw circle using glDrawArrays it displays quarter of [circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgtGC.png)

The VBO, generated by code, is correct. BTW there is no such coord as 0,0,0. 
It appears that it draws only positive vertices, but if I multiply vertices by -1 glDrawArrays draws it on other side of screen.
Here's my code:

```
uint un_vertexArraySize = 20;
float f_radius = 1.0f;
float f_degrees = 0;
GLfloat f_vert[un_vertexArraySize*3];
// Generate circle vertices
for (int i=0; i<un_vertexArraySize*3; i+=3)
{
    f_vert[i] = cos(f_degrees*M_PI/180)*f_radius;
    f_vert[i+1] = sin(f_degrees*M_PI/180)*f_radius;
    f_vert[i+2] = 0.0f;
    f_degrees += (360/un_vertexArraySize);
}
// Do buffer stuff
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, un_vertexArraySize*3,
             f_vert, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbind VBO
glBindVertexArray(0); // unbind VAO

// Start loop
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    shader.Use();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, un_vertexArraySize*3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    shader.UnUse();
// End loop
```

Frag shader:

```
#version 130
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor[0] = gl_FragCoord.x/640.0;
    gl_FragColor[1] = gl_FragCoord.y/480.0;
    gl_FragColor[2] = 0.2;
    gl_FragColor[3] = 1.0f;
}
```

Vert shader:

```
#version 130
attribute vec3 coord3d;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 temp = vec4(coord3d, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = temp;
}
```

I tried to google it or find on stackoverflow, but nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this right now but at glBufferData you use un_vertexArraySize*3, that is the number of elements, but I think you missed multiplying by 4 (bytes per float) so the size is specified in bytes. That would explain why you're only drawing a quarter of the circle

Comment: Just as a note: instead of multiplying by `4` I would multiply by `sizeof(GLfloat)` because then it is clearer with what the value is multiplied.

Comment: My bad for not mentioning it, that is a much better way